# Translating/Decoding a Foreign Security Principals to a readable name

Tags: php, mysql, active-directory

I have created a PHP script that will query an LDAP server, look at a list of Groups, and then get the Members array for each Group and dump the results into a MySQL database.  This all works great, but sometimes I get a Foreign Security Principal instead of a User.  The whole point of this exercise is to convert this list of Members into a readable list for non-IT people, so I need ideally, First Name, Last Name and if possible Username.  However the Foreign Security Principal is just a string of numbers.

We have about 80+ different trusted domains that it could have come from, so how can I work out what domain this foreign account belongs to, and also an attribute that I can use to search that other domain for the User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string of numbers should be the user's SID (e.g. S-1-5-...).  This is the attribute you would use to search.

The first part of the SID is the domain's SID, e.g. S-1-5-21-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890.  You should enumerate the domain's trusts, and find the domain with that SID.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  Is it possible to work out the Domain's SID dynamically with PHP or would I have to create a list manually from Active Directory for it to look at?

Comment: @sacredzero I only have experience with Windows domains, but if you bind to LDAP://domain.com/dc=domain,dc=com, you can read the objectSid attribute to get domain.com's SID.

Comment: So you would have to loop through all the domains, Binding to each to check if it's SID matches?  I imagine that it would be better to create a cached list of them...

Comment: I agree, you should create a cache (but you could do this dynamically).  I don't know how to enumerate the trusts in php, but in Win32 I would use [`DsEnumerateDomainTrusts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675976(v=vs.85).aspx).  This returns the SID without having to contact the domain.

Answer (score 0):

In an AD-LDS/ADAM directory, the attribute called "msDS-PrincipalName" on the foreignSecurityPrincipal contains the "domain\samAccountName". Example: "CONTOSO\jdoe"

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work on Active Directory FSP.

See: msDS-BindProxy 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221582.aspx